# Get uread message count in mongoose with Aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the ChatUser and Message schema like this.

```
var chatUser =  new Schema({
    chatID:{ type: ObjectId, required: true,ref: 'Chat' ,index:true},
    userID: { type: ObjectId, required: true,ref: 'User',index:true}, 
    lastMessageID: { type: ObjectId, required: false,'default':null,ref: 'Message'}
});

var message =  new Schema({
    from:{ type: ObjectId, required: true,ref: 'User' },
    chatID:{ type: ObjectId, required: true,ref: 'Chat'  },
    date:{type:Number,required:true,index: true},
    type:{type:Number,required:true},
    message:{type:String,required:false,'default':""}
});
```

Here I want to find the **unread message count of each chat for the user**. Here is what I am doing for that.

```
var query = {userID:userID,enable:true};
ChatUser.find(query ,'chatID lastMessageID',function(err,chatLastMessages){
    if(err){
        res.send(500);
    }else if(chatLastMessages.length){               
        var x= 0;
        var data = [];
        var task = function(){
            var lastMsgInfo = chatLastMessages[x];
            Message.count({_id:{$gt:lastMsgInfo.lastMessageID},chatID:lastMsgInfo.chatID}, function (err,count) {
                x++;
                if(err){
                    res.send(500);
                }else {
                    if (chatLastMessages.length > x) {
                        var result ={};
                        result[lastMsgInfo.chatID] = count;
                        data.push(result);
                        task();
                    } else {
                        var response = Response.createResponse(Response.RequestStatus.Success, "", data);
                        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
                    }
                }
            });
        };
        task();
    }else{
        //say no such chat or invalid chatID
        var response = Response.createResponse(Response.RequestStatus.Success,"Yo, You are all done. No unread message.",[]);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

This works perfect but I need to query the message schema for each chat. Is there any way may be [Aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) that I can find this in one query without recursion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653351/multiple-mongoose-count-queries-to-a-mongodb

Comment: @Molda Where I will write the $gt I try with 
`Message.aggregate([{ $match: {_id: {$gt:messageIds}}},{ $group: {_id: "$chatID",count: { $sum: 1  }}}], function (err, result) {});`this won't work.